# Collapse Data using Order By and Group BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am converting my mysql script to sql server script.

I want to sort data and then collapse the data by some criteria.

Lets take below example:

in Mysql:

[sql fiidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f26cf/2)

lets say we have table "test" and 3 column (colA,colB and colC)

Now I want to sort data by colA and colB and then want to pick first row of group colA,colB
I also like to find MIN(colC) for the group colA,colB

I have achieved in mysql by below query:

```
select colA, colB, min(ColC) 
from ( select * 
       from test 
       order by colA,colB) tempalias 
group by colA, colB
```

Now I case of sql server:

when I try to execute same query it gives me below error:

**The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.**

can anyone help me how to get same functionality in sql server same as I am doing in mysql.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should be the trick. Don't know if it's very efficient but you could give it a try

```
SELECT t1.cola, t1.colb, t1.colc FROM
    (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cola, colb) AS RowNumber
        FROM test) t1
JOIN
(SELECT cola, colb, MIN(RowNumber) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY cola, colb) AS RowNumber
        FROM test) AS SUBQUERY_01
        GROUP BY cola, colb) t2
ON t1.cola = t2.cola AND t1.colb = t2.colb AND t1.RowNumber = t2.RowNumber
```

If you want to change your order by criteria you have to edit both *OVER(ORDER BY cola, colb)* areas

Answer (score 0):

```
select colA, colB, min(colC) from test group by colA, colB order by colA, colB
```

Comment: I honestly don't know if this is the correct answer, but it is customary to provide some commentary along with your code.

Comment: I think it will group by the data first and then it will sort data. I want to sort data first and then need to apply group by so that I can pick up correct row of each group

Answer (score 0):

The following is the right way in both databases:

```
select colA, colB, min(ColC) 
from test t
group by colA, colB;
```

There is no need for the `order by` in the subquery.

Comment: I want to sort data first so when I use group by It will pick needed first row of group and that y I need to sort data first before I apply group By.

Comment: Why do you think you need to sort before you group? That makes no sense.

Comment: @RonakShah . . . `min()` gets the `minimum value.  That is what you need.  You do not need to sort in the subquery.  And, in most databases, that would have no effect either.

Answer (score 0):

```
create table test(cola int,colb int,colc int);

insert into test values(1,2,3);
insert into test values(1,2,4);
insert into test values(2,3,30);
insert into test values(2,3,39);
insert into test values(3,4,100);

select colA,colB,min(ColC) 
from test
group by colA,colB
order by colA,colB
```

You can just do that?

EDIT:

```
;with cte as (
select colA, colB, colC
, row_number() over(
    partition by colA, colB
        order by colC) as rn
from test
group by colA, colB)
select colA, colB, colC
from cte
where rn = '1'
```

Using a CTE to partition columns and order by.

Comment: I think it will group by the data first and then it will sort data. I want to sort data first and then need to apply group by so that I can pick up correct row of each group

Answer (score 0):

Your question as is doesn't really make sense. Either you want the smallest value for **colc** for every group or the first group-value of **colc** else. The solution of Nesuke for example does exactly what your fiddle example does. So why do you want to order by **cola** and **colb** before grouping?

Comment: I think I agree that this sql fiddle example is making people confuse, I do not want to find only MIN but I want pick first row of sorted data of group. there is possible that ordar by cols and group by cols are different. so first I need to sort data first by some cols and then on that result set I want to group by with some other columns. please let me if you are confuse or have any query

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think you have been confused. What you're wanting to do is find the minimum based on colC and the respective rows to go with that value. In this case if you look at my second solution (even though it spits the same results for the DDL given in this question), you will probably find your solution.